# What is default storage of tasks and functions in verilog? (automatic/static)?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Also, is the default storage different in case of system verilog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default storage is static. SystemVerilog is backward compatible with Verilog; existing Verilog code semantics cannot be changed. However, the storage of tasks and functions declared inside classes is always automatic. Please read [this pos](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/what-exact-difference-between-static-tasks/functions-and-automatic-tasks/functions-please-explain-clear-example)t for a complete explanation.